# Stacking after unstacking a data frame is different in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, stack, python-3.7

I created a DataFrame with 3 indexes. Later, I applied unstack method followd by the stack method. Then checked for equality of new and old data frames. Why are both of them different? Is unstacking not opposite procedure to stacking? Here is my  code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.Series([7]*9, index = [[1,2,3,2,4,9,6,7,9], ['a','c','f','a', 'k','f','c','d','a'], [np.nan]*9])
data2 = data.unstack().stack()
print(data2.equals(data))
```

The output returns False, but don't know why!

Comment: check the index

Comment: @ansev, I checked equality of indexes with this code : `print(data.index.equals(data2.index))` but also returned `False`

Comment: data2 is MultiIndex and data is not and that is why they are considered different